# There is an Error 1004: Application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys I am currently recording in a macro. I am turning raw datas in pivot table and automate it using macro. But whenever I press the button there is an error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Here are the sample of my codes in the VBA.

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "'Sheet1!R4C1:R279594C33'", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="'Sheet8!R3C1'", TableName:="'PivotTable3'", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

I hope you could assist me guys on this one.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you check whether the table or the sheet is protected?

Comment: it is not protected. thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the apostrophes in your `SourceData` and the `TableDestination` incorrect. The apostrophes should be only around the sheet name and not including the rows / columns towards the end. So, you got this:

```
"'Sheet1!R4C1:R279594C33'"
```

while it should be this

```
"'Sheet1'!R4C1:R279594C33"
```

The same applies to the TableDestination which should be `"'Sheet8'!R3C1"`.

Also, note that this code can only work once! This is due to the fact that you name the newly created `PivotCache` "PivotTable3". As there can be only **one** `PivotCache` by that name the second run of the above code will automatically fail (unless you delete the "PivotTable3" before running the above code).

Comment: hello thank you so much for this. how can I make it work for the second run without deleting the pivottable3? thank you so much.